# Is there a standard notation for the primitive of some root of unity?

Tags: notation, roots-of-unity

> Is there a standard notation for a) the primitive root of unity of some root of unity (or its inverse), and b) the quotient of the two?

e.g. let $f:\dfrac{n}{2^p}\mapsto \exp\left(\dfrac{2\pi i\cdot n}{2^p}\right)$ map the dyadic rationals modulo $1$ to the $2^n$th roots of unity.

If $\left\lvert \dfrac{n}{2^p}\right\rvert_2$ is the 2-adic valuation and $\dfrac{n}{2^p}\cdot\left\lvert \dfrac{n}{2^p}\right\rvert_2$ finds $n$ then is there a standard notation for the function that finds the equivalent values in $\Bbb{C}$?

Is there some standard notation for writing such things and if so, what is it; and are there associated notations I should know?

Comment: What do you mean by "the primitive root of unity"?

Comment: An $n^{th}$ root of unity is primitive if it is not a $k^{th}$ root of unity for some smaller $k$.  If I'm right, in the set $X_n$ I define there will be one unique such root.

Comment: @lulu sorry forgot the ping ^^

Comment: But you are not right.  There are several such.  For $n=4$, say, we already have $\pm i$.

Comment: In general there are $\varphi(n)$ primitive $n^{th}$ roots of unity. (pf:  if $\zeta $ is one then $\zeta^m$ is another iff $\gcd (n,m)=1$).

Comment: @lulu hmmn... I thought this construction was analogous to the p-adic metric on the Prufer 2-group via the group isomorphism from the dyadic rationals modulo $1$ to the $2^n$th roots of unity - which would give a unique value... but I have clearly gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: You can get a "preferred" primitive root by declaring some representation.  For instance, $\zeta_n=\exp\left(\frac {2\pi i}n\right)$.  But algebraically there is nothing special about that choice.

Comment: @lulu every dyadic rational modulo $1$ has a unique padic valuation. I'm trying to find that unique valuation in the $2^n$th roots of unity via the isomorphism $\dfrac{n}{2^p}\to \exp\left(\dfrac{2\pi i\cdot n}{2^p}\right)$.

Comment: Like I say, if (say) you fix an embedding of $\overline {\mathbb Q} \to \mathbb C$ you can then speak of $\zeta_n=\exp\left(\frac {2\pi i}n\right)$ but that will depend on the choice of embedding.  There is no "intrinsic" way to choose one.

Comment: @lulu I think I've edited the question to fix an embedding

Comment: @lulu p.s. is $\zeta_n$ a standard notation or was it just a convenient character to use?

Comment: Well, I'd say $\zeta_n$ was commonly used to denote a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity, though "standard notation" would be overstating things.  It is unusual to try to pick out one particular primitive root so it certainly isn't common notation for that.